# Can't get my Nvidia card working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel

I've just installed ubuntu on my laptop, and I haven't used ubuntu before hand, and as a result my knowledge is quite limited.

Anyways, everything is working well except for my graphics card. On my laptop I got both intel hd graphics and a 940MX from Nvidia. I've followed several guides to install the drivers for the 940MX and tried switching to it using prime-select from the terminal. The terminal tells me that the nvidia profile is already being used, but when I go to settings the graphics card is written as Intel HD.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers several times and now when I try to type nvidia-settings on the terminal, it gives me an error telling me that the Nvidia driver is not loaded. But the prime-select command still works and still tells me that the Nvidia profie is being used.

Thanks in advance and have a great day =)

Comment: What does the output of `glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer*"` show?

Comment: I've just tried running that command on the terminal and it says that vendor is Intel Open Source Tech.
and renderer is Intel(R) HD graphics.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me the output of this: `DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears -info | grep REND`

Comment: Thank you for help =), it says that GL_Renderer is Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 620, it also popped up a window with rendered spinning gears, and the animation seems to be running smoothly, don't know if it accounts for anything :)

Answer (score 0):

You could run `ubuntu-drivers devices` - grab the name of the intel driver and put it on the blacklist as described in Step 1 of Tutorial [GPU data processing inside LXD](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/gpu-data-processing-inside-lxd#1)